# In Fancy Box I want to add labels under the thumbnails

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add labels under the thumbnails but for the life of me I cant seem to figure it out.

```
<div class="sixteen columns">
<h3>Wood veneer finishes:</h3>
<p class="crumbs"></p>
    <div class="sixteen columns">
         <a class="fancybox-effects-c" href="woodveneers/VBO_Biscotti.jpg" data-fancybox-group="woodveneers" title="VBO Biscotti"><img src="woodveneers/VBO_Biscotti.jpg" alt="VBO Biscotti" width="72" height="72"/><p></p></a><a class="fancybox-effects-c" href="woodveneers/VBO_Biscotti.jpg" data-fancybox-group="woodveneers" title="VBO Biscotti">VBO Biscotti</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

If I add another image/thumbnail it places it below the original not next to it...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this

```
<a class="fancybox-effects-c" href="woodveneers/VBO_Biscotti.jpg" data-fancybox-group="woodveneers" title="VBO Biscotti">
<img src="woodveneers/VBO_Biscotti.jpg" alt="VBO Biscotti" width="72" height="72"/><br/>
VBO Biscotti
```

Comment: Yes, that works BUT add a second, third etc thumbnail. It seems so simple to to but i cant figure it out...